# XCode 15.3 Constantly Builds for Preview

Tags: xcode, widgetkit, xcode-previews

I am trying to create a widget for my app but I cannot use the Preview feature of Xcode.
Xcode enters a build loop and builds the project over and over. There is no error or message. There is only a loading spinner and lots of build.
It doesn't matter how much time I wait, it never finishes.

I tried to clean the build folder, delete all preview simulators, quit, and reopen the XCode but nothing helped.
[image: build logs]
[image: preview window]